# why does my fetch function return cors error

Tags: javascript, html, hosting

i am new to hosting and i dont know where to place the files in the hosting directory . i created a simple front end to test and a server using express.js .
i placed index.html /home/mytestsi/public_html/index.html folder in cpanel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
       <h1> welcome to mytestsite.com</h1>

         <script>
            fetch("http://localhost:40000"})
            .then(resp=>resp.json)
            .then(data=>console.log(data))
            .then(console.log("fetched"))
            .catch(err=>console.log(err));
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

i created a nodejs server using setupnodejs in cpanel . i then placed the file in 
/home/mytestsi/mytest/mytest.js in cpanel

```
const express = require ('express');
const cors = require ('cors');
const mysql = require ('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"mytestsi_root",
    password:"root1",
    database:"mytestsi_qbank"
});

// con.connect(err=>console.log(err));

const app = express();


app.use(cors());

app.get('/',(req,resp)=>{
    resp.('welcome to website');
})

app.listen(40000);
})
```

i am getting this output 
**fetched
localhost:40000/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(index):15 TypeError: Failed to fetch**

i added the following code in .htaccess as said by hosting customer care

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</ifModule>
```

still its give some 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:40000/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

i dont know how to proceed with this  . kindly help

Comment: it sounds like you have both the `index.html` and the node server on your hosting provider.  The `fetch` call in the `html` page is trying to access the `localhost` of the browser that is accessing the page (not your hosting provider).  It is `localhost` in reference to the user viewing the page.  In order for that to work, the user would need to be running a server locally (probably not what you actually want I suspect).  I guess a better question might be, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, it looks like you need to know some specifics of how your hosting provider runs/hosts/exposes that node server.

Comment: i placed index.html and node server in hosting provider. i am new to web development and i just need to clear this out . its bugging me a lot for the last couple of days . if i use php i place the index.php file in public_html and it works fine . but in node . i need my first page index.html to access the server . i used fetch to access the server (as to learn the testing process) . i need the server to respond to index.html file .

Comment: To talk to the server where the node app is hosted you need to send the request there.  This is where i am saying you need to know how it is hosted.  The fetch request would need to be sent to for example: `fetch('http://nodeapp.mydomain.com')`.  Without knowing how the node app is hosted it isn't easy to give you an answer as to how other than to say `localhost` definitely doesn't look correct.